# How to create animation sequence when character is moving at the same place

Tags: animation, unreal

I’ve created animation through UE Sequencer,but it seems moving in global space. How could I do animatian of a character in local space? Could somebody say which concept is supposed to be used here?
This is what I’ve done. The character moves away from its place while animating.
[image]
This is animation from starter pack. The character is moving at the same place. I believe the animation is working in local space. But how could I achieve it for my animation?
[image]

**UPDATE**
Eventually, I've created an animation just moving legs at place manually, without any special rules. Any ideas about how to do it correctly will still be appreciated.